# JavaScript show pop up on back button click

Tags: javascript, back-button

I have already searched for similar questions, but I cannot find what I am looking for.

I already have a function to display a pop up image when the user has switched tabs, but I also need the pop up to display when the user has clicked the back button and does not take you back to the previous page on the first click.

I have looked into `popstate` and `pushState` but I don't think I need this as the url isn't changing. I just need something to display when the hit the back button. Any ideas?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+show+popup+back+button+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Any help would be appreciated guys.

Comment: Please click `do some research` link above